# pandas using str in rolling does not lead to NaN when the data is not enough

Tags: pandas

let's say we have weekly data,

```
$pd_tmp
            SCF/CME_C  SCF/CME_S  SCF/CME_SM
Date                                        
2018-06-19   0.797769   0.955308    0.609879
2018-06-26   0.858320   1.066278    0.641302
2018-07-03   0.872486   1.086672    0.656232
2018-07-10   0.908582   1.054378    0.664331
```

If I apply rolling mean with number of windows, I could get nan if data is not enough

```
$pd_tmp.rolling(2).mean()
            SCF/CME_C  SCF/CME_S  SCF/CME_SM
Date                                        
2018-06-19        NaN        NaN         NaN
2018-06-26   0.828044   1.010793    0.625590
2018-07-03   0.865403   1.076475    0.648767
2018-07-10   0.890534   1.070525    0.660282
```

However, if I apply str as rolling window, then the behavior is different

```
$print pd_tmp.rolling("8D").mean()
            SCF/CME_C  SCF/CME_S  SCF/CME_SM
Date                                        
2018-06-19   0.797769   0.955308    0.609879
2018-06-26   0.828044   1.010793    0.625590
2018-07-03   0.865403   1.076475    0.648767
2018-07-10   0.890534   1.070525    0.660282
```

How do I make sure nan is there when data is not enough.

Comment: That is not string , that is freq...

Answer (score 2):

You could add a count to your agg function then eliminate all resulting records that do not have "enough" count.

```
df_out = df.rolling("8D").agg(['mean','count'])
df_out.columns = df_out.columns.map('_'.join)
df_out.where(df_out.iloc[:,2]>1).filter(like='_mean')
```

Output:

```
            SCF/CME_C_mean  SCF/CME_S_mean  SCF/CME_SM_mean
Date                                                       
2018-06-19             NaN             NaN              NaN
2018-06-26        0.828045        1.010793         0.625590
2018-07-03        0.865403        1.076475         0.648767
2018-07-10        0.890534        1.070525         0.660281
```